# How to set the notification dots on a Moto G6?

Tags: notifications, motorola-moto-g, 8.0-oreo

I activated the notification dots on my Moto G6 following this process: Settings > Apps & notifications > Notifications > Allow notification dots, but the dots are not appearing.

Did I do something wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: If you're using stock moto launcher, then go to settings->moto app launcher->app notifications, then enable both 'On' and 'Allow notification dot'.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue.  Notification dots are enabled on all apps but don't work.

I do not have any 3rd-party notification apps.
I have cleared the cache and data from the "Moto App Launcher" application and restarted it.  No difference.

I did, just now, download an application for notifications and it works.  So annoying.  Moto App Launcher obviously has some issues/flaws.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down from top of screen.  If it says 'Notifications paused by do not disturb', then that's the issue.  Probably activated it by an accidental swipe/touch.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Special App access -> Notification Access -> Enable Moto App launcher

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you do not have Data Saver turned on. This will prevent the notifications from appearing and will also cause email delivery issues.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case here. OP didn't say he wasn't receiving notifications at all, but only the notifications dots.